# Can't find the syntax error in my SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I keep getting a syntax error in my SQL SELECT statement.  I know it is an issue with the `DateDiff`function at the end of the statement, but I can't seem to find the correct format.  I am sure it is simple but I am not finding it.

```
"SELECT 
     tblAllSchedules.[Schedule Name], 
     tblAllSchedules.[Arvl Sta],  
     (' & Format(DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]),'ddd') & ')' AS [Day], 
     DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]) AS [Date], 
     tblAllSchedules.Metal, tblAllSchedules.Type, 
     tblAllSchedules.[Key ID], tblAllSchedules.[LAA NB], 
     tblAllSchedules.[LAA WB], tblAllSchedules.[LUS NB], 
     tblAllSchedules.[LUS WB], tblAllSchedules.[Sub Fleet], 
     'Original', '" & csName & "', (' & DateDiff('d', '" & FSun & "',  [Tables]![tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time])+ 1 & ')' AS CompSchedDay"
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Check the brackets in the `DAY` column

Comment: The 'Day' column works fine.  The code statment worked until I added my 'DateDiff' function.  It probably has to do with my combination of quotes and operators, but I can't find the right one.

Comment: What type is `FSun`?  What values does it hold?

Comment: `FSun` is a date vaule.

Comment: Is it an actual date field, or a string representing a date?

Comment: actual date field.

Answer (score 1):

Someone just had the winning answer posted but it went away before I could respond.  Here is the corrected syntax.

```
    SELECT tblAllSchedules.[Schedule Name], tblAllSchedules.[Arvl Sta], 
Format(DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]),'ddd') AS [Day], 
DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]) AS [Date], 
tblAllSchedules.Metal, tblAllSchedules.Type, tblAllSchedules.[Key ID], 
tblAllSchedules.[LAA NB], tblAllSchedules.[LAA WB], tblAllSchedules.[LUS NB], 
tblAllSchedules.[LUS WB], tblAllSchedules.[Sub Fleet], 'Original', '" & csName & "', 
DateDiff('d', '" & FSun & "' ,  [tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time])+ 1 AS CompSchedDay
```

I quess I had it too mudled and more complicated than it needed to be.  Only issue now is correcting the new "aggrigated function" error.  Thank you all for your quick and helpful comments.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized it was basically the same thing @Gustav posted.

Comment: Your Answer will be much easier to read if you spread it accross more than one line.  `Gustav`'s Answer is one illustration of how this can be done.

Comment: oh, well there was something different about it, or I missed something in Gustav's when I tried it.  Thank you.

Comment: adjusted the look of the answer for easier reading per Toonice.

Comment: Well, that may work by pure luck; but it is not the correct syntax for DateDiff. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

FSun must be a valid date expression. So try:

```
Dim FSun As String
FSun = Format(YourFSunDateValue, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

"SELECT 
    tblAllSchedules.[Schedule Name], 
    tblAllSchedules.[Arvl Sta],  
    Format([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]),'ddd') AS [Day], 
    DateValue([tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]) AS [Date], 
    tblAllSchedules.Metal, 
    tblAllSchedules.Type, 
    tblAllSchedules.[Key ID], 
    tblAllSchedules.[LAA NB], 
    tblAllSchedules.[LAA WB], 
    tblAllSchedules.[LUS NB], 
    tblAllSchedules.[LUS WB], 
    tblAllSchedules.[Sub Fleet], 
    'Original', 
    '" & csName & "', 
    DateDiff('d', #" & FSun & "#, [tblAllSchedules]![Arvl Local Date/Time]) + 1 AS CompSchedDay
FROM
    tblAllSchedules"
```

Comment: Still no luck, but I am sure I needed those too.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT [Schedule Name],
       [Arvl Sta],
       '(' & FORMAT( DATEVALUE( [Arvl Local Date/Time] ), 'ddd') & ')' AS [Day], 
       DATEVALUE( [Arvl Local Date/Time] ) AS [Date],
       Metal,
       [Type],
       [Key ID],
       [LAA NB],
       [LAA WB],
       [LUS NB],
       [LUS WB],
       [Sub Fleet],
       'Original',
       '''' & csName & '''',
       '(' & ( DATEDIFF( 'd', FSun, DATEVALUE( [Arvl Local Date/Time] ) ) + 1 ) & ')' AS CompSchedDay
FROM tblAllSchedules;
```

Firstly, you have used `tblAllSchedules.` for some lines and `tblAllSchedules!` for others.  Unless you have both a table *and* a form called `tblAllSchedules`, you should stick to the former to refer to fields in your table.  The latter is used to refer to fields and controls in a form or report.  For now, I am assuming that your statement refers only to fields in a table called `tblAllSchedules`.

Secondly, if all the fields are coming from the same table, namely the one specified in your `FROM` clause, then you do not need to specify the table's name against each field.  If any are coming from a form, then you should use notation like `frmAllSchedules!txtDate`.

Thirdly, try to give each field its own line in the `SELECT` part of the statement.  This makes it easier to find a targeted field as well as to recognise when you are referring to two separately selected fields or two fields being used in some manner to form another (both of which appear to be occurring on your final line).

Fourthly, you appear to be trying to place `(` and `)` around string representations of date values, e.g. `(Wednesday)` and `(12)`.  To do this you will need to place `'` on *both* sides of the opening bracket as well as the closing bracket, and concatenate it with your value.

Fifthly, you appear to be trying to place a `'` on either side of `csName` in the output.  To do that you need to start with `''` to signify the start and end of your string.  In the middle of these place two more `''` (giving you `''''`), which is how you tell it that you want it to return a string with a single `'` as its contents.

Sixthly, you should consider giving an alias to `'Original'` and `'''' & csName & ''''` - Access will arbitrarily give them one if you don't.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a comment accordingly.

Comment: Corrected slight error.  Explanation nearly complete.